# Can't install or run Ionic after accidentally reinstalling it

Tags: ionic-framework

I had ionic installed and running properly.
Accidentally I installed beta version

```
npm install ionic@beta
```

I did that without having CMD run with administrator, after that ionic command wasn't being  recognized anymore, so I tried installing ionic again, but no luck, I tried uninstalling it and then installing it again but also no luck, the error I get when I install it:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-313f575d
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-313f575d' -> 'C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\ansi-313f575d' -> 'C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\ansi'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because when installed beta version without administrator privilege it created PATH variable in user scope which points only to npm directory, and this variable overrides the system PATH variable so CMD uses the user scope one, which causes ionic installation to fail.

Deleting the user's scope PATH variable and re-installing ionic fixed the issue.